# Open File Dialog causes a dll issue in WPF application

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, dll, openfiledialog

I have a WPF Application Project in VS2012 using .Net framework 4.0.
My WPF application has some references to Managed C++ dlls.

I would like the user to be able to choose a file to open but when i call the *OpenFileDialog* before some function from a managed C++ dll I get a *System.BadImageFormatException*, but if i send a hard coded path instead of letting the user choose using the OpenFileDialog then the application works fine.
When i looked up the *System.BadImageFormatException* all i found was that this refers to format issues but i am running on a x64 bit machine and compiled everything including the c++ dll to x64 bit format and i still keep getting this exception.

Is there some known problem with the OpenFileDialog that i dont know about?

Here is an example of my code:

```
private void WorkingFunction()
{
    String filePath = @"C:\MyFile.txt";
    // Calling the managed c++ functions...
}

private void NotWorkingFunction()
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    Nullable<bool> result = fileDialog.ShowDialog(); 
    if(result == true)
    {
        String filePath = fileDialog.FileName;
        // Calling the managed c++ functions...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to compile code in x86 expilicitly meaning you are going to run application in 32-bit mode.

Or else you can use the same class wrapped in Windows forms.

```
System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
```

Comment: I cannot compile my application to x86 and when I tried to use System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog I had the same problem.